# Can a smart capture form on a cloud page be auto-submitted?

Tags: marketing-cloud, smart-capture

We have a smart capture element on a cloud page where we would like to have an auto-submit functionality for the form's fields into a DE.

The smart capture form currently works when we manually press "submit" - which is fine. But we'd like to be able to also auto-submit form data after a certain amount of time.

Before I try to code anything I wanted to know whether this was possible in a smart capture form in the first place.

I have done some research in the past days but could not find any information on whether it'd be even worth trying.

I have not written any code, I jut wanted to ask this general question first.

Thanks in advance for any helpful information you guys have from experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with smart capture forms. If you want to do this you have to implement forms that you develop with usual web techniques like ajax / javascript / jquery / ssjs and so on.

You would then use these techniques to call functions that insert the data. Or you would technically call other webpages and post data to them on certain actions. Like field.focus or something like that. Keep in mind that you will need to have a unique id that the functions know where to write the data.

[Here](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/build-html-forms-without-smart-capture/) is a great Article from Ivan Razine.